# The map $m \to m\sigma(m)$ is not injective.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let
$$\tau(n) = \sum_{d \mid n}{1}$$
be the divisor function,
$$\omega(n) = \sum_{p \mid n}{1}$$
be the prime divisor function,
$$\varphi(n) = \#\{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n : \gcd(k,n) = 1\}$$
be Euler's totient function, and
$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n}{d}$$
be the classical sum-of-divisors function.

I am reading this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.09287) by Gabdullin and Iudelevich, where they showed that:

- The map $m \to m\tau(m)$ is **not injective**.  (They give the example $18\tau(18) = 27\tau(27)$, and therefore, $18t\cdot\tau(18t) = 27t\cdot\tau(27t)$ whenever $\gcd(t,6)=1$.)
- The map $m \to m\omega(m)$ is also **not injective**.  (For any prime $q \geqslant 5$, we have $18q = 9q\omega(9q) = 6q\omega(6q)$.)
- The map $m \to m\varphi(m)$ is an injection.  (The details are in the first paragraph of Section 4 in page 8.)

So, now I wonder:

- Is the map $m \to m\sigma(m)$ an injection?

I ran the following [Pari-GP script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNDDQUUgD8irhvMw0DY0KreLM9NxEjQpNBVtbhUoor1JTU0FNTUGjQsHGTqFSU6egKDOvRKNCJy0xuQRkoKZOJYwNVAoEANlnHa0=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to search for integers $u \neq v$ such that
$$u\sigma(u) = v\sigma(v)$$
in the range
$$1 \leqslant u \leqslant 100, 1 \leqslant v \leqslant 100,$$
the computer search found:

```
12[2, 2; 3, 1]14[2, 1; 7, 1]
14[2, 1; 7, 1]12[2, 2; 3, 1]
48[2, 4; 3, 1]62[2, 1; 31, 1]
60[2, 2; 3, 1; 5, 1]70[2, 1; 5, 1; 7, 1]
62[2, 1; 31, 1]48[2, 4; 3, 1]
70[2, 1; 5, 1; 7, 1]60[2, 2; 3, 1; 5, 1]
```

- This shows that the map $m \to m\sigma(m)$ is **not injective**, as we have
  $$336=12\sigma(12)=14\sigma(14),$$
  $$5952=48\sigma(48)=62\sigma(62),$$
  and
  $$10080=60\sigma(60)=70\sigma(70).$$

**Note that all known examples $u, v$ below $100$ are even.**  [Extending the search](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjTsOgCAQRK-yFVnMFmAt3sBDEA2GQjFIsXt78T_VvMlkJqSM7CyBNcYQhIryYwyI3OxxXjyyBudAHhKtQSlAhq4Huf2QJmRqr579I_ki2nJcS-0EP5bzWJO8vg5WHYREJiw=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) until $u, v \leqslant 1000$, and limiting it to values of $u$ and $v$ such that $uv$ is odd, then we obtain

```
315[3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1]351[3, 3; 13, 1]
351[3, 3; 13, 1]315[3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1]
```

- This means that
  $$196560=315\sigma(315)=351\sigma(351).$$

The Pari-GP interpreter of Sage Cell Server crashes as soon as search limits of $u, v \leqslant {10}^4$ are specified.

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS**

> > **(1)** Are there more examples of positive integers $u \neq v$ such that $uv$ is odd and
> > $$u\sigma(u)=v\sigma(v)?$$

> > **(2)** If the answer to *Question* **(1)** is *YES*, are there **infinitely many** such examples?

> > **(3)** Are there any examples of positive integers $u \neq v$ such that $uv$ is odd, $\gcd(u,v)=1$, and
> > $$u\sigma(u)=v\sigma(v)?$$

Comment: FYI, [A337874](https://oeis.org/A337874) does not have such an example.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Will take your lead to investigate more into this problem (and the accompanying OEIS sequences).

Answer (score 2):

infinitely many odd pairs
$$  u = 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot w$$
$$  v = 3^3 \cdot 13 \cdot w  $$
for odd  $w$   such that $$ \gcd(w, 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13) = 1.   $$

After running much higher, it now **appears** that these are **all** the successful pairs. Worth trying to prove, easier tasks would include ruling out $u=p$  prime, $u = p q $  semiprime.

Comment: And for $p=11$.

Comment: @paw88789  yes, indeed $p$  can be anything relatively prime to $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 = 1365$

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @WillJagy!  +1

Comment: @WillJagy:  Did you mean "$w=p$ prime, $w=pq$ semiprime" instead of "$u=p$ prime, $u=pq$ semiprime" in your last sentence?

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris  no, I meant to start over, drop the  3, 13, 5, 7 factors, see if the easiest  apparent restrictions can be proved. Long road to prove (if true) that my pairs are all the examples.....

Comment: Okay, now I understand, @WillJagy!  =)

Answer (score 1):

I can answer question 1 in the affirmative.

For example $3465\cdot \sigma(3465)=3861\cdot \sigma(3861)$

Comment: I found several more examples; all seem to have a common factor of $9$ (relevant to your question 3).

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @paw88789!  +1